# PHP скрипт завершается без причины

Tags: php, cron

Имеется PHP cronjob скрипт, который импортирует данные в БД WordPress. Данных много, ориентировочное время выполнения должно быть 1.5-2 часа. Импорт одного товара ~0.3 сек. Самое тяжелое в одной операции - загрузить картинку ~500кб к товару.

Если коротко, то скрипт выглядит так:

```
foreach($brands as $brand) {
        foreach ( $brand->products as $product ) {
            $this->import($product);
        }
    }
```

Проблема в том, что скрипт завершается на какой-то итерации внутреннего цикла без причины и каких либо уведомлений. С различным интервалом времени (~40-50 минут) после запуска для одних и тех же импортируемых данных (они всегда одинаковы на тесте).  По логике ничего не должно останавливать его.

Все сообщения об ошибках включены, логирую всё что можно, но в логах всё пусто.

В чём может быть причина? Куда копать?

Comment: память кончается и скорее всего вы не все логируете

Comment: Разве, когда кончается память не должно вылезать error'a?

Comment: но иной проблемы не вижу. Может быть как вариант, если вы тяните с интернета информацию, то есть еще предположения

Comment: Ну вот конкретный пример. Я вытянул 10 000 товаров ОДИН раз, в каждом по ~15 текстовых полей плюс ссылка на картинку. Всё поместил в двухуровневый массив. И по нему цикл сверху и проходится. Есть идеи?

Comment: @Node_pro да, вы правы. 96 мб переполняются и скрипт вылетает. Вот только почему без ошибки? -_-

Comment: А как вы записываете логи или выводите ошибки?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72172/discussion-between-zhi-v-and-node-pro).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Памяти не хватает, для полного завершения работы скрипта